# Javascript Array.prototype.map not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript

When I try to use Javascript's map with parseInt (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), only the first element appears to call the callback correctly.

```
version = '10.9.8.11.11';
v = version.split('.');
vp = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    vp[i] = parseInt(v[i]);
}

alert(vp + '\n' + v.map(parseInt) + '\n');
```

gives

```
10,9,8,11,11
10,NaN,NaN,4,5
```

as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/69wpB/

What am I doing wrong? I get the same behavior in Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: This is documented on the very page you've linked to (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Tricky_use_case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have an answer and a comment linking to the documentation page where the problem is explained so I won't add another link to a documentation.

I'll just add a more convenient way to parse than to define a new function :

```
var numbers = version.split('.').map(Number);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) passes multiple arguments to the callback.

[`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) uses the second argument as the radix to determine how to parse the integer.

```
map(function (str) {
    return parseInt(str, 10);
})
```

Should work as expected.